# Using GeoPandas generated .gpkg in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geopandas, geopackage, python-3

I am using GeoPandas to create .gpkg files. Using `GeoDataFrame.to_file()`

When opening the files in ArcMap, it takes a long time updating the file extent. Files already have an spatial index as this is a GeoPackage.

Is there a way to specify the GeoPandas GeoDataFrame extent and code that's in the GeoPackage?

Also, files open in ArcMap with a .main prefix in front of my specified layer name which may be an ArcGIS thing.

It’s looking good in QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.main is not a problem. With SQLite you can attach other databases and the name (or schema) of the master database is "main".  Most other clients just does not show it.

The extent of each table is stored into metadata table gpkg_contents http://www.geopackage.org/spec121/index.html#_gpkg_contents. The GeoPackage standard says

> The bounding box (min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y) provides an informative
> bounding box of the content. Applications may use this bounding box as
> the extents of a default view but there are no requirements that this
> bounding box be exact or represent the minimum bounding box of the
> content. The values are in the units specified by that CRS.

If ArcGIS or any other client wants to get extent that is guaranteed to be accurate it must read every single feature. Usually it is waste of time. The reason for allowing the bbox in the metadata to be an estimate is that otherwise it should be calculated again after each insert/delete/edit.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will look at the specs.  Do you know if I can add this to the metadata table using geopandas or will I need to go with Gdal OGR once the file is created?

Comment: I bet that the metadata is there but ArcGIS does not utilize it. You can open the GeoPackage database with any SQLite client and have a look. You can also complain to your ESRI support but they may say that they don't care because your GeoPackage is created with Geopandas. Say then that GeoPackage is international standard and they should show in which way the Geopandas GeoPackage violates the standard if that's the problem.